# Beginning Java Method Practice

Tags: java, arrays, methods

Method: fillArray

the method accepts a non-null String variable as an argument. Return a char array that has been filled from the String passed to the method, each element set to the corresponding character in the string. 
public char[] fillArray(String var)

Method: stringArray

the method accepts an array of chars as an argument if the chArray is null or length is zero, returns an empty string if chArray is not null, return a single string with each of the characters in the array in the string. 
public String stringArray(Char[] chArray)

Method: productMatrix 
0 <= n <= 100 if n is out of bounds, return null if n is greater than or equal to zero, return a n x n matrix with each element of the matrix set to row index * column index. 
public int [] [] productMatrix(int n)

Method: sumOfSquares 
the method accepts an array of ints if the array is null or of size zero, return 0 if the size of the array is greater than or equal to 1 return an int equal to the sum of the square of each element of the array 
public long sumOfSquares(int[] intArray)

Method: incPosArray 
the method accepts an array of ints if the array is null or of size zero, simply return if the size of the array is greater than or equal to 1 increment each positive element of the array, leaving the negative elements and the elements equal to zero set to their incoming values 
public void incPosArray(int[] intArray)

```
public class Q3 {


public char[] fillArray(String var){
    System.out.println( "fillArray not implemented");
    return null;
}


public String stringArray(char[] chArray) {
    System.out.println( "stringArray not implemented");
    return null;
}


public int[][] productMatrix(int n){
    System.out.println( "productMatrix not implemented");
    return null;
}


public long sumOfSquares (int[] intArray) {
    System.out.println( "sumOfSquares not implemented");
    return -1;
}


public void incPosArray (int[] intArray) {
    System.out.println( "incPosArray not implemented");
    return;
}


public static void main (String[] args) {
    Q3 q3 = new Q3();

    //Put your test code here

}
}
```

Comment: Whats your question?

Comment: How do you construct these methods given the conditions in the description?

Comment: More specifically how do you construct these methods with the proper if/else and for statements?

Comment: If you're not familiar with the Java language, try this [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html) to get started.

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly homework, so I ain't doing it all for you, but I will help you get one so maybe you have some ideas what to do with the rest...

this is you fill array method thing...

```
public char[] fillArray(String var){
    //is the string NOT null? 
    if(var != null){

        // create new a new char array with a length equal to the passed in String  
        char[] splitString = new char[var.length()];

        /*String function - for breaking down our string in chars. 
        * args 1 = the letter we want to start from, in this case the begging i.e. 0
        * args 2 = the letter we want to end at...well the end of the string so just pass its length
        * args 3 = the char array we made and want to put the chars into!
        * args 4 = no idea, just leave it as zero, something to do with offset
        */
        var.getChars(0, var.length(), splitString, 0);
        //then just return the string
        return splitString;
    }

    //I am assuming that if the string is null we return null????
    //this only calls if the string is null
    return null;
}
```

Test it with the bellow code...

```
    char [] array = fillArray("hello");

    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
```